# Cannot find Foreign key constraint index

Tags: laravel, postgresql, migration

my `run_tasks` table has foreign key `completer_guest_id` which I need to refer to some other table's column.

```
Schema::table('run_tasks', function (Blueprint $t) {
            $t->integer('completer_id')->nullable();
            $t->foreign('completer_id')->references('id')->on('users');
            $t->integer('completer_guest_id')->nullable();
            $t->foreign('completer_guest_id')->references('id')->on('tasks_guests');
        });
```

But I cannot find the index: [`run_tasks_completer_guest_id_foreign`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZX55.png)
because of which I cannot drop the foreign key constraint and delete the column in this migration:

```
Schema::table('run_tasks', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->dropForeign('run_tasks_completer_guest_id_foreign');
            $table->dropColumn('completer_guest_id');
            $table->integer('completer_guest_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('completer_guest_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('guests')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

and I am getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy9iD.png), When I run `\d run_tasks` I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leFYF.png)
Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: I find that sometimes separating out the queries can fix some of the problems when it comes to dropping indexes, worth a try

Comment: Thanks @user10341554 it was worth a try becuase it worked!

Answer (score 1):

drop the table and try to separate the creation and the foreign keys assignment

```
    Schema::dropIfExists('run_tasks');
    Schema::create('run_tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('completer_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('completer_guest_id')->nullable();
        $table->index(['completer_id', 'completer_guest_id']); 
    });       
    Schema::table('run_tasks', function(Blueprint $table) {           
        $table->foreign('completer_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('completer_guest_id')->references('id')->on('guests')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Comment: Hi, do you know why separating these works? It's something I've had to do but I haven't found a definite answer as to why this works.

Comment: That's a mistery ... i found this issue while I was creating a [Migration Generator](https://github.com/simonecosci/wms/blob/master/resources/views/admin/templates/migration.blade.php)